# Activiti 5.21 to 6.0.0 migration issue on Async mail task

Tags: java, upgrade, activiti

I am in the process of migrating from Activiti version 5.21 to 6.0.0.  Aside from the expected changes (some unexpected), I've run into an interesting issue when executing an Asynchronous Mail task.  The Mail task sends the message as expected and no errors are thrown, but the retry on failure flow appears to be followed despite the successful operation.  After 3 attempts (and 3 emails being sent), the Job moves to the dead letter table as if an error has happened.  the error message in the table is

"JobEntity [id=SOME ID] was updated by another transaction concurrently"

What's strange is that there are no errors thrown from Activiti.  I've set my log level to trace and nothing seems out of the ordinary.

According to the User guide (https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#failRetry), I would expect an attempt to retry the operation if something failed, but in this case, nothing has failed and the mail was sent properly.

I can avoid this error if I set the Process config AsyncExecutorNumberOfRetries property to zero (configurationImpl.setAsyncExecutorNumberOfRetries(0);), but this doesn't seem like something I should have to do.

The default value of the asyncExecutorNumberOfRetries property in the ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl is 3 so that explains the 3 attempts, but I am wondering why the engine is not capturing the successful mail event and treating it as a failure.

Here is my bpmn model code:  it's just a simple start/end event with an email and adhoc task.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:activity="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:klover="http://klover.io/bpmn" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn">
<bpmn:process id="MigrationTest3" name="Migration Test 3" isExecutable="true" klover:category="tenant1|Incident:TaskCategoryType">
<bpmn:documentation>test 3</bpmn:documentation>
<bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Start Event" activity:initiator="initiator">
  <bpmn:documentation>This element denotes the start of the process instance</bpmn:documentation>
  <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0xdrrlx</bpmn:outgoing>
</bpmn:startEvent>
<bpmn:serviceTask id="ServiceTask_0p317lq" name="MIgration Test 3" activity:async="true" activity:type="mail">
  <bpmn:documentation>This element denotes the service to send email</bpmn:documentation>
  <bpmn:extensionElements>
    <activity:field name="from">
      <activity:expression></activity:expression>
    </activity:field>
    <activity:field name="to">
      <activity:expression>me@test.org</activity:expression>
    </activity:field>
    <activity:field name="subject">
      <activity:expression>Test Migration 3</activity:expression>
    </activity:field>
    <activity:field name="text">
      <activity:expression>testing re-enabling async mail task - did this   send 3 times?</activity:expression>
    </activity:field>
  </bpmn:extensionElements>
  <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_0xdrrlx</bpmn:incoming>
  <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0wboybt</bpmn:outgoing>
</bpmn:serviceTask>
<bpmn:endEvent id="EndEvent_11vu7d5" name="Undefined End Event">
<bpmn:documentation>This element denotes the end of the process instance</bpmn:documentation>

<bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_17ff3nr</bpmn:incoming>
</bpmn:endEvent>
<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0xdrrlx" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="ServiceTask_0p317lq" />
<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0wboybt" sourceRef="ServiceTask_0p317lq" targetRef="UserTask_1sghk67" />
<bpmn:userTask id="UserTask_1sghk67" name="Testing Adhoc task after email" activity:assignee="tenant1|718abdcf-e192-11e5-b7f0-9f235e785c94" activity:priority="0" klover:formType="Adhoc">
<bpmn:documentation>Testing the new execution id change</bpmn:documentation>
<bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_0wboybt</bpmn:incoming>
  <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_17ff3nr</bpmn:outgoing>
</bpmn:userTask>
<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_17ff3nr" sourceRef="UserTask_1sghk67" targetRef="EndEvent_11vu7d5" />
</bpmn:process>
<bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
<bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="MigrationTest3">
<bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
<dc:Bounds x="44" y="84" width="36" height="36" />
<bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      <dc:Bounds x="34" y="120" width="55" height="12" />
    </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
<bpmndi:BPMNShape id="ServiceTask_0p317lq_di" bpmnElement="ServiceTask_0p317lq">
    <dc:Bounds x="285" y="128" width="100" height="80" />
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="EndEvent_11vu7d5_di" bpmnElement="EndEvent_11vu7d5">
    <dc:Bounds x="663" y="281" width="36" height="36" />
    <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      <dc:Bounds x="644" y="317" width="74" height="24" />
    </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
<bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_0xdrrlx_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_0xdrrlx">
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="80" y="102" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="183" y="102" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="183" y="168" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="285" y="168" />
    <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      <dc:Bounds x="198" y="125" width="0" height="0" />
    </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
<bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_0wboybt_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_0wboybt">
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="385" y="168" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="452" y="168" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="452" y="207" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="453" y="259" />
    <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      <dc:Bounds x="467" y="187.5" width="0" height="0" />
    </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
  <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="UserTask_1sghk67_di" bpmnElement="UserTask_1sghk67">
    <dc:Bounds x="403" y="259" width="100" height="80" />
  </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
<bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_17ff3nr_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_17ff3nr">
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="503" y="299" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="581" y="299" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="581" y="299" />
    <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="663" y="299" />
    <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      <dc:Bounds x="596" y="299" width="0" height="0" />
    </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
  </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
</bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
</bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error is about comitting transaction after work is done. It's known behaviour of activity engine - you have to either roll back the work or make it possible to do it multiple times. You can meet similar things in high load environment with multiple executors and tasks. In this case you can use exclusive jobs (describes in next section, 8.7.3 of user guide), for most scenarios they lock process before execution of async job.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue here was that in our DEV env, we start up multiple instances of the process engine when each developer is working on the app.  As I was the only person working at the time, initially I did not think this was the issue. Turns out we had an old app server running the engine.  Subsequently, it was running in a different timezone on AWS than my local instance.  This is what was causing the perceived failure as the lock time was in UTC on this AWS instance and I was running on local MST.

After setting up a contained local environment, my async mail tasks executed as expected... 1 time